# Python Virtualenv Linux Mint. Работает не корректно

Tags: python, linux-mint, virtualenv

По порядку
1. Устанавливаю через Terminal виртуальное окружение `virtualenv v`
2. Активирую его в папке `source v/bin/activate`
3. Активация срабатывает, в терминале как и положено отображается `(v)`
Но не работает само окружение. При команде `pip3 freeze` он показывает все пакеты установленные на `pip3` и при установки например `pip3 install numpy` пакет ставится глобально. Окружение создаётся только под `pip` а не под `pip3`. В гугл нашёл следующий вариант: установить окружение таким образом:
`virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3.6 venv` . В таком случае окружение устанавливается для `pip3` но не смотря на то что `pip3 freeze` показывает только те пакеты которые я ставил в окружение, при запуске скрипта он их не видит. Подскажите как выйти из проблемы.

Comment: ОС Linux. Ставил sudo pip3 install virtualenv

Comment: Покажите точную последовательность действий от создания virtualenv (вариант с `-p` является правильным, если что) до неудачного запуска скрипта с numpy — копированием текста из терминала или хотя бы скриншотом

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Установить virtualenv:

   ```
   python3 -m pip install --user virtualenv
   ```
2. Создать virtualenv:

   ```
   python3 -m virtualenv env
   ```
3. Активация virtualenv:

   ```
   source env/bin/activate
   ```
4. Выйти из virtualenv:

   ```
   deactivate
   ```

Comment: Забыл указать у меня Linux. Это подойдёт?

Comment: Да, это как раз под него

Comment: Тоесть сейчас пакет для pip3 virtualenv удалить?

Comment: ну да ,удали ,и установи как я прописал

Comment: Установил, активирова, далее проверил через pip3 freeze никаких пакетов нет. Установил pip3 numpy , далее проверил через pip3 freeze, пакет поставился. Запускаю скрипт где import numpy as np и он выдаёт что нет такого модуля.

Comment: А если запускаю скрипт через python main.py а не через python3 то тогда работает

Comment: Это нормально что через python main.py а не через python3 ?

Comment: @IT-KOT посмотрите содержимое каталога `v/bin` чтобы увидеть список команд, доступных в виртуальном окружении. Если там нету python3, то не используйте его (а если есть, то это странно)

Comment: Есть в каталоге python3 и python3.6